# Exception when running three.js example using iewebgl

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, three.js, webgl, compatibility

I'm trying to use the [iewebgl](http://iewebgl.com/) and having trouble running one of the examples from three.js, [the webgl_loader_obj](http://threejs.org/examples/webgl_loader_obj.html).  I am getting the following error:

`SCRIPT445: Object doesn't support this action
iewebgl.html, line 134 character 5`

which points to this line

```
// texture
var manager = new THREE.LoadingManager();  <!-- here  -->
manager.onProgress = function ( item, loaded, total ) {

    console.log( item, loaded, total );
};
```

I also tried commenting out the texture and model portions and loading the object without the manager but I would receive the following error:

`SCRIPT445: Object doesn't support this action
OBJLoader.js, line 19 character 3`

which points to this line

```
THREE.OBJLoader.prototype = {

constructor: THREE.OBJLoader,

load: function ( url, onLoad, onProgress, onError ) {

    var scope = this;

    var loader = new THREE.XHRLoader( scope.manager );  <!-- here-->
    loader.setCrossOrigin( this.crossOrigin );
```

I tried both creating canvas and getting WebGL context from JavaScript and creating WebGL context with helper.

I'm using ie 10 with r.46 of three.js. When I use r.61 of three.js I get the following exception

`SCRIPT5007: Unable to get property 'getExtension' of undefined or null reference 
three.min.js, line 8322 character 2`

which is

```
} catch (Zb) {
    console.error(Zb)
}
Na = j.getExtension("OES_texture_float"); <!-- here -->
j.getExtension("OES_texture_float_linear");
va = j.getExtension("OES_standard_derivatives");
```

Any idea what may be causing it?

Comment: r.46? That's two years old. Whatever you do, update to r.61.

Comment: I've updated my question with the results. I'm using r.46 because I've seen a few examples that have used iewebgl successfully and seems to get further before throwing an exception.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to solve my issue using the **Creating canvas and getting WebGL context from JavaScript** example

```
<div id="container"> 
    <script id="WebGLCanvasCreationScript" type="text/javascript">WebGLHelper.CreateGLCanvasInline('renderCanvas', onLoad)</script>
</div>
```

I then placed both the `init()` and `animate()` calls in the following block leaving out the global vars
    var container, stats;

```
var camera, cameraTarget, scene, renderer;
function onLoad() {
    <!-- require(["js/Three.js"], function () { -->
    init();
    animate();
    <!-- }); -->
}
```

I didn't use the `require` code, but included it in case anyone else runs into a similar problem and finds they need it.

Finally, had to change the render code to the following. (I left the original commented)

```
var externalCanvas = document.getElementById('renderCanvas');
renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({ 'canvas': externalCanvas, 'clearColor': 0xffffff });
<!-- renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer(); -->
<!-- renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer( { antialias: true, alpha: false } ); -->
```

Comment: can you please provide a fiddle about this? Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

If you use the un-minified version of three.js, I think you'll see the problem is the _gl object (j in the minified version) is null. It also looks to me as if three.js will throw an exception, log the message "Error creating WebGL context" and then proceed to try to use the _gl object. :)

Did you see that message in your console? Here's the un-minified source where I think your error occurs.

```
function initGL() {

    try {

        var attributes = {
            alpha: _alpha,
            premultipliedAlpha: _premultipliedAlpha,
            antialias: _antialias,
            stencil: _stencil,
            preserveDrawingBuffer: _preserveDrawingBuffer
        };

        _gl = _canvas.getContext( 'webgl', attributes ) || _canvas.getContext( 'experimental-webgl', attributes );

        if ( _gl === null ) {

            throw 'Error creating WebGL context.';

        }

    } catch ( error ) {

        console.error( error );

    }

    _glExtensionTextureFloat = _gl.getExtension( 'OES_texture_float' );
    _glExtensionTextureFloatLinear = _gl.getExtension( 'OES_texture_float_linear' );
    _glExtensionStandardDerivatives = _gl.getExtension( 'OES_standard_derivatives' );
```

Is WebGL supported on your IE? Do other webgl tests work? I don't have IE Win8.1 preview but I am curious to know if three.js works with it.

Comment: I'm using IE10, I believe win 8.1 preview is using IE11 which should support webgl out-of-the-box but still experimental.